# Powershell (Get-ADUser -identity).someproperty not showing result

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am trying to search for individual properties of an AD-User, when I run

```
(Get-ADUser $userName).$targetProperty
```

I get nothing
When I run

```perl
Get-ADUser $userName | select $targetProperty
```

I get the property and a blank underneath.
BUT when I run.

```perl
Get-ADUser $user -Properties *
```

I get the full list & when I look at $targetProperty, there is a value already there.
My environment is 1 DC, its local, and I am in Admin mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the target property you are trying to get. If it is not one of the properties in the default set (the ones you get when you just run `Get-ADUser testuser`), it isn't in the result set, so you can't get to it elsewhere in your command.

Here are the default properties.

```
DistinguishedName : CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : Test
Name              : Test User
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 94916bd1-008e-409f-a1b3-eaXXXXXX266e
SamAccountName    : TestUser
SID               : S-1-5-21-23XXXXXX88-41XXXXX83-1941XXXX34-32584
Surname           : User
UserPrincipalName : TestUser@example.com
```

Let's say the property you want is `Title`. So your first command is this:

```
(Get-ADUser testuser).Title
```

`Title` is not in the default set of properties, so the part in parentheses doesn't include a `Title` property, so the result of the combined command is nothing.

Second attempt:

```
Get-ADUser testuser | select Title
```

That gives you the word "Title" as the header of the column, but there is still no value for it, because the first part of the command still doesn't include a `Title` property in the results.

Third attempt:

```
Get-ADUser testuser -Properties *
```

Aha! That's getting close. It includes the `Title` property, along with a whole bunch of others that you don't care about right now.

Fourth attempt:

```
(Get-ADUser testuser -Properties *).title
```

That's it! This combination gets all of the properties of the user (so that includes `Title`) and then only shows you the `Title` property.

**Optional:** You can make it a bit faster by not bothering to ask for the 100+ properties that `-Properties *` gives you, and only get the default properties plus `Title`, with this:

```
(Get-ADUser testuser -Properties Title).Title
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following lets me get the info, but why was it not working with my other commands?

```perl
(Get-ADUser $user -Properties *).$targetProperty
```

Comment: Probably because you're pulling all properties, then grabbing one property out of all of them. That's why using piping to `select $targetproperty` works.